# Can't Add Event Handler Into Button With ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a jQuery plugin installed on a website I'm working on. The plugin in question adds a modal dialogue to the website when a certain image is clicked. I wanted to add a second button to this modal, to close the window in addition to the close button that already does so, and I managed to do this by creating a div for the button in the HTML. Note that the content for the modal is set in the plugin's content variable, so looks like this:

```
content: '<p>Want to get in touch? Drop us an email at:</p><br/>   
         <p><input type="text" id="inset" name="inset"     
         value="shoesfromlastnight@gmail.com"       
         onClick="javascript:this.focus();this.select();"  
         readonly="readonly" size="30"/></p> <br/> 
         <span id="appendto"><p>We look forward to hearing from you!</p></span> 
         <div type="button" id="crmbutton">Okay</div>'
```

...where #crmbutton is the div I want to use as a button. For some reason, though, I'm having trouble with setting the event handler to the button created there in order to make it close the modal. It sounds simple enough, but for some reason won't work when I do:

```
$("#crmbutton").click(function() {     
this.close();
});
```

Although I couldn't find any documentation on it, the close() method I'm using here is the very same that is used by the plugin's own X button to close the modal. For what it's worth, here's that button's code, first to create the close button and then, using the .on method, to close the modal on click:

```
this.closeButton = jQuery('<div/>', {'class': 'jBox-closeButton jBox-noDrag'}).on('touchend click', function(ev) { this.isOpen && this.close({ignoreDelay: true}); }.bind(this));
```

I also copied everything after the .on method and applied it to my code, but wasn't successful with that either.

I also tried other approaches, like adapting the code above to create the button on the fly, and then appending or prepending it using the append/prepend methods. This worked, but only when appending to the modal's container, which always added the button outside of the container. I had no luck with appending the button after certain elements, like the `#appendto` - the button just wouldn't be added.

Does anyone know where I could be going wrong here? This is the first time I've worked with jQuery, and it's frustrating me to no end. Thanks!

Comment: Please put this into a fiddle.

Comment: What does it mean when you're calling native `close` method of a native `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you're not calling the close method in the correct scope. In your eventlistener, 'this' points to the button. But in the code that you looked at, 'this' has been changed to another scope with the .bind() method.

```
$("#crmbutton").click(function() {     
    /* 'this' points to the element #crmbutton, which doesn't have a close method */
    this.close(); 
});
```

The example code, look at the bottom where the .bind() method is used.

```
this.closeButton = jQuery(
    '<div/>', 
    {
        'class': 'jBox-closeButton jBox-noDrag'
    }
).on(
    'touchend click', 
    function(ev) {
        this.isOpen && this.close({ignoreDelay: true}); 
    }.bind(this) /* The scope is being set to another 'this' */
);
```

[Documentation about the .bind() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Thanks for this. I had a feeling it would come down to a scope problem, but my knowledge of it is incredibly basic. It looks like I'll have do some more reading up on scope, and also on jQuery's bind method. Thanks again.